# Typescript create index signature to proxy access to child object

Tags: typescript

I am quite new to Typescript so apologies if this is not a great question.

I have an object (A) that wraps another object (B), and provides some methods to act on B. I am trying to proxy access on A so that the value for that key on B will be returned. A contrived code example would be as follows:

```
type AType = {
  state: StateType
  doubleSomeVal(): number;
} & StateType

type StateType = {
   someVal: number;
}


type StateTypeKey = "someVal"

class A implements AType {
    state: StateType;

    doubleSomeVal() {
      return this.state.someVal * 2;
    }

    constructor(state: StateType) {
      this.state = state;
    }

    static create(state: StateType) {
      return new Proxy(new A(state), { 
        get(target: A, key: StateTypeKey) {
          return target.state[key] || target[key];
        }
     });
    }
}
```

But then TS complains because it can't see that my class A has the properties of StateType belonging to it - which makes sense, but I'd like to solve it if possible.

Comment: What is `integer`?  What's `"otherKeys"`?  Why are you using `A.state[key]` and `A[key]` instead of `target.state[key]` and `target[key]`?  How do you plan to use the results of `new A()` or `A.create()`?  Please consider editing the code here into a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  My suggestion is to break this into two steps.  First write some ES2015+ JavaScript that works the way you want, and then come up with typings for it.   Good luck!

Comment: Edited with suggested corrections, thanks.

Comment: I wrote the contrived example above quickly hence I had made a couple of syntax errors, but the example (now that I'm accessing target[key] not A[key] works fine as ES2015 code, the problem is specifically related to Typescript, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I am skeptical that the above code could work fine in JavaScript considering that it still contains at least two typographical errors.  Even after those are fixed, `new A({someVal: 123}).someVal` is undefined.  If that is your intent, then remove `implements AType` from your code in TypeScript and the error will go away.  If that is *not* your intent, then something is not the way you want it to be at runtime.  An [mcve] should be something you've personally put into an IDE and confirmed that it has all and only the problems you are facing.  Hope you get the help you want.  Good luck again!

Comment: I've fixed all typographical errors, thanks for pointing those out.
`new A({someVal: 123}).someVal` being undefined is not the intent, but inevitable. 

The intent is that A will be instantiated via the static `create` method, which returns the proxy object that is intended to offer access to `state` as  properties on `A`. 

TS doesn't like this as someVal doesn't exist on A, and so my question is whether it's possible to provide a type for A that would facilitate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you actually don't want `A` to implement `AType`, since it is only the output of `A.create()` which does that.  So I'd change your `A` class to something like this:

```
class A {
  state: StateType;

  doubleSomeVal() {
    return this.state.someVal * 2;
  }

  constructor(state: StateType) {
    this.state = state;
  }

  static create(state: StateType) {
    return new Proxy(new A(state) as A & A["state"], {
      get(target, key) {
        return Reflect.has(target.state, key)
          ? Reflect.get(target.state, key)
          : Reflect.get(target, key);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Notice that the target of the `Proxy` is [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to be `A & A["state"]` which is essentially the same as `AType`.   This assertion is necessary somewhere since the compiler can't easily verify that the proxy will act as that intersection.  I also changed the implementation of the `get` handler to be a little friendlier to the compiler (the `key` parameter will really be `string | number | symbol` and I don't feel comfortable narrowing to some literal union there) and to circumvent any issues with possibly falsy values for `target.state[key]`.  But it's basically the same.

Then I suppose you'd use it like this:

```
const a = A.create({ someVal: 4 });
console.log(a.state); // {someVal: 4}
console.log(a.someVal); // 4
console.log(a.doubleSomeVal()); // 8
```

Which compiles fine and gives the desired output.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIBVzQLxQN4CgpQGcB7AWwgDV4AbALigDsBXEgIwgCcBuHAX25wDGVeAQJQAgtjyEESOnEQo0-fABMijFlQgxSFagAoAlFPz52EYI3b0owABYBLAgDoCsiG72UqUAFRQAEzc+Dw40gJE9O7sjALAROwG7oryHqiQJrhmdk6uKUhQmAUQIVBh0gWOAlACForJHmmKGRBZ0uaW1rb0EADuUAAK7EQAHiAGvQPijYomIhJQAGQSANoARCXrALoANKY5UADmlgYI7CfA+wDWECDth2YWVjZQAEoQAGba8S72Imd4BdLG4PDc7kYOo8oAB+d5fH7AFyXQHApElcH3KGPOgfb4QX4o86XTFGMo5MIUsnSMIVSLRYBQeBFCQuOoQBpYQjeah0AAs5Wp9OI2hcVCIRwM8FBc04UAA9PLsMQyD5+WFhURReLJdKVfoqGSFUq+YIoiLPDqpS51JptLpVYYjEbFVAABzhIA)